# var declaration hides interfaces inside modules

Tags: typescript

the following code

```
interface Foo {
}
declare var Foo: {
    new() : Foo;
}

module Bar {
    export interface Baz {
    }
    export declare var Baz: {
        new() : Baz;
    }
}

function f(p:Foo) {
}

//function b(p:Bar.Baz) {
//}
```

compiles fine, however if I comment in the last two lines tsc.exe generates "Expected type"-Error
It seems like declaring a var inside a scope hides the interface declaration.

Any ideas?

Comment: What behaviour would you expect here - you have given two things the same name?

Comment: I would expect that if I needed a in interface, the interface would come up and if I needed an object the object would come up. TypeScript-Team does it this way in `lib.d.ts` - have a look at http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2bee84410e02#typings%2flib.d.ts ... And anyway.. My real problem is that the behaviour differs in usage inside and outside of modules...

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are trying to do, but may be wrong.

Here is an example of create a declaration similar to the one in your example:

```
interface Foo {
}

declare var Foo: {
    new() : Foo;
}

declare module Bar {
    export interface Baz {
    }
    export class Baz {
        new() : Baz;
    }
}

function f(p:Foo) {
}

function b(p:Bar.Baz) {
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this outside of declarations - which is why I have converted the module to a declaration.